Voltage dividing with 3 resistors at the terminal of BJT's emitter (CB mode.)

from Problem 11.18, Fundamentals of Microelectronics(2nd edition), Behzad Razavi, Wiley

from Fundamentals of Microelectronics(2nd edition) Solutions, Behzad Razavi
One is the question and the other is its solution. After I solve it, I checked solution (2nd image) and wondered why the V_x/V_in is different from my answer.
My approach for getting V_x/V_in was in terms of signal path. If the signal begins from V_in, it passes R_B and split into R_B and Z_in of BJT. In that sense, I thought V_x/V_in = Z_in / [(Z_in || R_F/(1-gmRc) + R_B]. But the solution says Z_in / [(Z_in)+(R_B||R_F/(1-gmRc)].
I can't understand why R_F/(1-gmRc) is dealt with R_B, not Z_in.  Can you explain this confusion?

dumbdumbdumb - Hi, Where did the question image come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online & public, please [edit] the question & add the webpage/PDF name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL). If the source is offline (e.g. book or private intranet) then [edit] the question & add full source details e.g. title, author, page, publisher, edition. TY (More rules in the [tour] & [help].)

Sorry for my mistake and Thanks for letting me know!

It seems that you are right. For me also the Zin is equal to Zin = RB + (ro/(1 - gm RC) ||1/gm)

Since my learning courses for electrics & electronics got tangled, I was worried if that made me miss something. Therefore it was hard to think that the solution must be wrong. Thank you for your comment and have a good day! @G36
